# Overriding AddComment method magento with pending status

Tags: magento

Kindly help me. I am trying to override

> Sales_order/addComment

Method in magento
But i messed up to find where this method exists.
My motive is to attach a file with the comment so users can download from comments.
I successfully added input field for file uploading but cant find this method of

> sales_order/addComment

so i can save my file with this comment
![enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 0):

You can find this action in Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController

You can override the controller by adding this in your config file:

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Namespace_Module_Adminhtml before="Mage_Adminhtml">Namespace_Module_Adminhtml </Namespace_Module_Adminhtml >
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

And after you can create you file:

app/code/local/Namespace/Module/controllers/Adminhtml/Sales/OrderController.php

And rewrite the addCommentAction();
Since controllers are not autoloaded, you have to include it in your file like this:

```
    <?php
require_once('Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php');

class Namespace_Module_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController
{
    public function addCommentAction()
    {
        // DO THINGS
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi jonaPkr Thank You So much You save my Whole day thanks alot

Comment: Hi john I already override Mage_Adminhtml_Sales in config file <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <use>admin</use> can i add one more router to the same ?
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Nishu_Translator after="Mage_Adminhtml_Sales">Nishu_Translator_Adminhtml</Nishu_Translator>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>    
    </routers>

Comment: What are you doing with this rewrite ? Is it working ? if you rewrite Mage_Adminhtml like in my post and place your controllers in appropriate subfoler, a second rewrite should be not necessary. Don't you have a github repository or somethid esle to show your code ?

Comment: I already override this controller but i was using after in my controller instead of before.JonaPkr i Want to attach my uploaded file with this comment i add new field inamed file in the table of comment history but cant upload my file through its ajax request